# How to create a copy of text file which is inside jar and extract the copy into a particular destination on my system?

Tags: java, text, jar, extract

Suppose I have text.txt inside a jar Project.jar. How to create a copy of text.txt and extract that copy into a specific folder in local drive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the `java.util.jar` API.  Specifically, take a look at [`JarFile.getEntry()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/jar/JarFile.html#getEntry-java.lang.String-) and [`JarFile.getInputStream()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/jar/JarFile.html#getInputStream-java.util.zip.ZipEntry-).  For example:

```
JarFile jarFile = new JarFile(new File("Project.jar"));
ZipEntry entry = jarFile.getEntry("text.txt");
InputStream is = jarFile.getInputStream(entry);
// write InputStream to file
```